# how to display the image width,height and angle values in canvas after dropping the image

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, html5-canvas

Hey Everyone I am new to html5 canvas as I would like to know is there any possibility of getting the image height,width and angle values while resizing and rotating.The image which displays what i want.[image]
I want that process after dropping in to canvas as i searched Google for this couldn't find relevant answer almost everyone is showing the positions of image in canvas that is to kept in code but i want the image should should display its values automatically by click on dimensions button.Thanks in advance any help would be great.

The image should display its dimensions in canvas according to image like if image is changed(or re-sized or rotate automatically the dimensions should change using button click function).

Comment: Depends upon how are you resizing and rotating the image!

Comment: yes @MJQ if we resize the image it automatically should display the image height,width

Comment: You have to keep track of image coordinates, i.e where is it being drawn and its width and height! If you have this you can display them!

Comment: is there any library to use for this

Comment: How are you dragging and resizing the drawing?

Comment: Like this? http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/  Then you have to carefully determine where the starting and ending coordinates are being stored. From them you can determine the needed data!

Comment: http://pastie.org/6359765
here is the code

Comment: I implemented the drag and rotate functionality using JS events and i was doing that with storing the coordinates and using them when dragging and rotating!

Comment: okk but my boss asked me to display their values in canvas itself
like if we click dimensions button it should display in canvas

Comment: He can ask he is the boss!

Comment: ya he is the boss but im new to this one so no idea about how to use @MJQ

Comment: I can give you hints about how to get the values and not do it! So, You can see into your resize and rotate functions, there will be values you need!

Comment: okk can we discuss in chat room

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25356/discussion-between-mjq-and-geethika)

Answer (score 0):

You can play with canvas in the following manner

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas">Your browser does not support the canvas tag.</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Draw blue rectangle
    ctx.fillStyle = '#0065BD';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 125, 75);

    // Draw white X
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = "15";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(125, 75);
    ctx.moveTo(125, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 75);
    ctx.stroke();

</script>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for ur help this is not what i want actually if u saw the image u will understand what is my concept i can resize and rotate my image in canvas but im unable to display the height,width and angle values while resizing,rotating

Comment: I think for that you have to play with jquery where you assign x & y-axis dynamically . So when you move from 1 position to another , you see the dynamic change in position of your cursor which is the height & width of your image

Comment: thanq for ur suggestion i will try with that